# Violin Plot Width in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to plot one full violin plot next to multiple half-violin plots using ggplot. I'm plotting the full violin plot using geom_violin(), and plotting the half violin plots using geom_violinhalf from the "see" package, with scale = 'width'. However, this produced a figure with the full violin plot appearing significantly thinner than the half-violin plots, as seen in the code below. I've tried the three built-in "scale" options in ggplot.

Is there a way to plot one full violin plot and several half-violin plots using one function? Or is there a different way I can manually set the width of the full violin plot?

Thanks!

```
#install.packages("vioplot")
#install.packages('ggplot2')
#install.packages('scales')
library(ggplot2)
library(vioplot)
library(scales)

df1 = as.data.frame(matrix(NA, nrow = 1000, ncol = 2))
colnames(df1) = c('x','y')
df1[,2] = rnorm(1000,10,5)
df1[,1] = rep(-5, 1000)
df2 = as.data.frame(matrix(NA, nrow = 10000, ncol = 2))
colnames(df2) = c('x','y')
df2[,1] = sample(seq(0,70,5),10000,replace=TRUE)
df2[,2] = rnorm(10000,10,5)
df = rbind(df1, df2)

ggplot(df, aes(x=x,y=y))+
  geom_violinhalf(data=subset(df,df$x != -5), aes(x=x, group = x), scale = 'width', fill = alpha('red', 0.2), color = alpha('red',0.2))+
  geom_violin(data = subset(df, df$x== -5), color = alpha('red', 0.2), fill = alpha('red', 0.2))+
  geom_point(size = 1.2, col = alpha('grey', 0.2))+
  theme_classic()
```

**EDIT**

The previous code was incorrect, apologies. How could the first violin be expanded if the dataframe was instead as follows, with each of the violin plots grouped by 'd' instead of by 'x':

```
df1 = as.data.frame(matrix(NA, nrow = 10000, ncol = 3))
colnames(df1) = c('d','y','x')
df1[,2] = rnorm(10000,10,5)
df1[,1] = sample(seq(-5,70,.1),10000, replace=TRUE)
for(i in 1:nrow(df1)){
  if(df1[i,'d'] < 0){df1[i,"x"] <- -5}else
    if(df1[i,"d"] >= 0 & df1[i,"d"] < 5){df1[i,"x"] <- 0}else
      if(df1[i,"d"] >= 5 & df1[i,"d"] < 10){df1[i,"x"] <- 5}else
        if(df1[i,"d"] >= 10 & df1[i,"d"] < 15){df1[i,"x"] <- 10}else
          if(df1[i,"d"] >=15 & df1[i,"d"] < 20){df1[i,"x"] <- 15}else
            if(df1[i,"d"] >= 20 & df1[i,"d"] < 25){df1[i,"x"] <- 20}else
              if(df1[i,"d"] >= 25 & df1[i,"d"] < 30){df1[i,"x"] <- 25}else
                if(df1[i,"d"] >= 30 & df1[i,"d"] < 35){df1[i,"x"] <- 30}else
                  if(df1[i,"d"] >= 35 & df1[i,"d"] < 40){df1[i,"x"] <- 35}else
                    if(df1[i,"d"] >= 40 & df1[i,"d"] < 45){df1[i,"x"] <- 40}else
                      if(df1[i,"d"] >= 45 & df1[i,"d"] < 50){df1[i,"x"] <- 45}else
                        if(df1[i,"d"] >= 50 & df1[i,"d"] < 55){df1[i,"x"] <- 50}else
                          if(df1[i,"d"] >= 55 & df1[i,"d"] < 60){df1[i,"x"] <- 55}else
                            if(df1[i,"d"] >= 60 & df1[i,"d"] < 65){df1[i,"x"] <- 60}else
                              if(df1[i,"d"] >= 65 & df1[i,"d"] < 70){df1[i,"x"] <- 65}else
                                if(df1[i,"d"] >= 70 & df1[i,"d"] < 75){df1[i,"x"] <- 70}else
                                  if(df1[i,"d"] >= 75 & df1[i,"d"] < 80){df1[i,"x"] <- 75}}
```

Comment: You might be interested in this https://github.com/RainCloudPlots/RainCloudPlots

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The widths will equalize by default if you convert x to a factor:

```r
ggplot(df, aes(x=factor(x),y=y)) +
  geom_violinhalf(data=subset(df,df$x != -5), aes(group = x), 
                  scale = 'width', fill = alpha('red', 0.2), 
                  color = alpha('red',0.2)) +
  geom_violin(data = subset(df, df$x== -5), 
              color = alpha('red', 0.2), fill = alpha('red', 0.2)) +
  geom_point(size = 1.2, col = alpha('grey', 0.2)) +
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can keep `x` numeric and use the `width` parsmeter of `geom_violin`. Here I'll set it a bit too wide at `width = 8` for demonstration purposes, but the ideal seems to be about `width = 5`:

```r
ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_violinhalf(data = subset(df,df$x != -5), aes(group = x), 
                  scale = 'width', fill = alpha('red', 0.2), 
                  color = alpha('red',0.2)) +
  geom_violin(data = subset(df, df$x == -5), width = 8,
              color = alpha('red', 0.2), fill = alpha('red', 0.2)) +
  geom_point(size = 1.2, col = alpha('grey', 0.2)) +
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

---

**EDIT**

To add the points from column d, we can do:

```r
ggplot(df1, aes(x=x,y=y)) +
  geom_violinhalf(data=subset(df1,df1$x != -5), aes(group = x), 
                  scale = 'width', fill = alpha('red', 0.2), 
                  color = alpha('red',0.2)) +
  geom_violin(data = subset(df1, df1$x== -5), width = 5, 
              color = alpha('red', 0.2), fill = alpha('red', 0.2)) +
  geom_point(aes(x = d), size = 1.2, col = alpha('grey', 0.2)) +
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

Comment: Hello, thank you for your response. I have edited the original post to include a correct dataframe - my previous dataframe was not correctly grouped, apologies. Thank you! The width() argument works, although I'd prefer it to be scaled correctly by ggplot so it's not accidentally manually over or under-exaggerated.

Comment: @wileyh it seems to give me the same result.

Comment: how would I plot a scatterplot of the points over that, with the x values as 'd' instead of 'x'?

Comment: @wileyh incidentally, you can replace that whole pile of `if...else` with the single line `df1$x <- floor(df1$d /5) * 5)`

Comment: That is terrific, thank you @Allan Cameron. For plotting the continuous points over it, would I have to re-define the data selection within geom_point?

Comment: @wileyh see my update - just a simple additional `aes(x = d)` inside `geom_point`

Comment: OK - that worked for the plot where the violin plot's width = 5. Is there a way to do that in the first code example you posted? Thanks!

Comment: @wileyh that's more difficult because the x axis is now a factor level. Perhaps the best thing to do is keep it numeric, then have optimal width calculated automatically - for example, in this set-up `width = mean(diff(sort(unique(df1$x))))` would work, and would work whether `d` was rounded to the nearest 5, the nearest 10, the nearest 7 or whatever to produce x

Comment: Excellent - that works perfectly. Thank you so much for your help @Allan Cameron !!